# Looping reshape and matmul in OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp

I was debugging some piece of parallel code and found a reshape operation messed up OpenMP. This is a demo to reproduce the issue. I am not very familiar with using OpenMP yet so I'd like to know the reason about what am I doing wrong here, and if there is a better way to do things, (i.e. how best to have reshape and matmul nested in do loops). I have read OpenBLAS as a potential solution but would first like to know why. Thank you in advance

```
program unittest

    complex*16, save, dimension(10,10) :: testmat
    integer :: i
    real :: t0, t1, t2

    !$call OMP_set_num_threads(12);
    !$call OMP_set_dynamic(.FALSE.);
    testmat = 0.d0;

    call cpu_time(t0);
    !$OMP parallel
    !$OMP DO
    do i=1,1000000
         testmat = reshape(reshape(testmat,(/100,1/)),(/10,10/));
    end do
    !$OMP END DO
    !$OMP end parallel
    call cpu_time(t1);
    do i=1,1000000
         testmat = reshape(reshape(testmat,(/100,1/)),(/10,10/));
    end do
    call cpu_time(t2);
    print *, 'parallel time, ', t1-t0, 's, single thread time, ', t2-t1, 's'

end program unittest
```

Compiled with gfortran on MinGW. Output on my machine is

(with parallel)   10.01 s
(single thread)   0.328 s

CPU registers less than 20% usage overall for the parallel case which probably means something is holding up OpenMP?

====================

Edit:

Thank you. Some clarification, the following is okay-ish, as in, the parallel version does not run *slower* (both completes around the same amount of time)

```
    !$OMP parallel private(testmat2)
    !$OMP DO
    do i=1,1000000
        testmat2 = testmat * 10.d0;
    end do
    !$OMP END DO
    !$OMP end parallel
```

but this runs much slower in parallel than on single thread (takes 50x more time in parallel than single)

```
    !$OMP parallel private(testmat2)
    !$OMP DO
    do i=1,1000000
        testmat2 = reshape(reshape(testmat,(/100,1/)),(/10,10/));
    end do
    !$OMP END DO
    !$OMP end parallel
```

So... what is special about reshape that causes this?

Comment: The reshape loop cannot be parallelized as it is. There is a loop carried dependency that cause a race condition. In fact, the loop is not dependent of `i`.

Comment: For software that crashes, reducing down to a minimal reproducible example that shows the bug as you have done is very helpful. However, for performance problems things aren't so simple. There are many reasons why a parallel code might be slower than a serial code, and it is probable that your minimal code is slow for reasons unrelated to why your original code is slow.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Very good point here too, give me some time and I will try to post code that make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a reshape operation is not an operation. It's a matter of internal book keeping: you're telling Fortran that an 100x1 array is now to be interpreted as 10x10, or so. This basically takes zero time.

Next, you have a parallel do, which means that the loop iterations get divided over the available threads. Meaning: they get done multiple times. So now you have something that is some internal book keeping, and you do that multiple times. I'm only a little surprised that that gives strange results.

If you want to use a parallel for, you need to have a loop where each iteration does something involving the loop index. For instance `v(i) = ....`.

Comment: `reshape` isn't an operation indeed, but a function. Why do you call it a "matter of internal book keeping"? With `reshape(y, shape)` you aren't telling Fortran to interpret `y` as now being of a different shape, but you are creating a brand new entity, involving a copy of data (unless optimized away).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My full program does put things into their respective indices (yea, it's pointless to do the same thing a thousand time) but this is what I reduced it down to when trying to pin down the reason it's not using all CPU time, just as an example. Maybe this example isn't the best to illustrate the issue?

@francescalus that's what I was thinking too, if the data being copied and something is happening to the copying process, and somehow messed with the parallel division of loops.

Comment: If this is a condensation of a bigger program, then you left out the wrong things. Start by moving the reshape out the parallel loop, and show us what you are actually parallelizing.